# Codable and optional JSON fields

Tags: json, swift, codable

There are lots of APIs that respond with appropriate HTTP status code if something went wrong, but there are also APIs that always respond with 200 status code describing error in specific JSON fields. This is exactly my case. So I made a `BasicResponse` protocol that requires any `Codable` struct to have those mandatory fields:

```swift
protocol BasicResponse: Codable {
    var response: String { get }
    var message: String? { get }
}
```

My `Codable` struct now looks like this:

```swift
struct GetTicketsResponse: Codable, BasicResponse {
    var response: String
    var message: String?

    var tickets: [Ticket]
}
```

And I also created sort of middleware decoder to identify an error on early stages:

```swift
class AdvancedDecoder {

    func decode<T: BasicResponse>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

        // Check if session is valid
        if (result.message == "Session invalid") { throw AdvancedError.invalidSession }

        return result
    }

}
```

But I noticed a problem with this approach. If something fails on a server it returns JSON that have those `response` and `message` fields but does not have `tickets` field, so decoding the response always fails. I could've marked `tickets` array as an optional type `var tickets: [Ticket]?` but it seems like a very strange workaround to me. Here are two JSONs for the reference:

```
// If everything went smoothly
{
    "response" : "OK",

    "tickets" : [...]
}

// If something went wrong
{
    "response" : "ERROR",
    "message" : "Session invalid"
}
```

So how do I handle this kind of scenarios? I bet there is a way better solution to this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `var tickets: [Ticket]?` is a solution

Comment: What's the issue with making `tickets` as optionals? This is how this kind of scenarios are handled until both the success and failure cases are entirely different.

Comment: @PGDev it seems kinda strange to me because it either has `tickets` field or an error field. There are no other scenarios so making `tickets` an optional type only to prevent decoding errors seems overcomplicated for this simple of a case.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion an enum with associated types is the most efficient solution

```
enum Response : Decodable {

    case success([Ticket])
    case failure(String)

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case response, message, tickets}

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let response = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .response)
        switch response {
            case "OK":
                let ticketData = try container.decode([Ticket].self, forKey: .tickets)
                self = .success(ticketData)
            case "ERROR":
                let errorMessage = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
                self = .failure(errorMessage)
            default:
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .response, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid response string")
        }
    }
}
```

And use it

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    switch result {
        case .success(let tickets): print(tickets)
        case .failure(let errorMessage): print(errorMessage)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make two different `Response` struct for success and failure. If success fails to decode try decoding with failure response.

```
struct SuccessResponse: Codable {
    var tickets: [...]
}

struct FailureResponse: Codable {
    var response, message: String
}

func decodingFunction(data: Data) {
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(SuccessResponse.self, from: data)
        let tickets = response.tickets
        //...
    } catch {
        do {

            let failureResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(FailureResponse.self, from: data)
            let message = failureResponse.message
            //...
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```